# How to merge two data such that it gives entries of the first data which are not in second data

Tags: r

For example:

```
Data1:
      customer_id  product sales
1           1       mixer     3
2           2       mixer     3
3           3       mixer     3
4           4       toaster   3
5           5       toaster   2
6           6       lcd tv    2
7           7       lcd tv    1
8           8       lcd tv    1


Data2:

    customer_id       No_of_products_ordered    response
1           2                    two             positive
2           4                    two             positive
3           6                    two             negative
4           8                  three             positive
5          10                  three             positive
6          12                   five             negative
7          14                   five             negative
```

The output should be:

```
       customer_id  product sales

1           1       mixer     3
3           3       mixer     3
5           5       toaster   2
7           7       lcd tv    1
```

that is it removes those id from data1 which are also in data 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this is a duplicate, but the answer is:

```
Data1[!Data1$customer_id %in% Data2$customer_id,]
```

Comment: I have tried the command: merge(Data1,Data2,all.x=TRUE,all.y=FALSE) and similar commands which are working in saas but not here

Comment: If you take a look at `? merge`, you'll see that `all.x=TRUE` is not what you want because it will copy all records from both dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various things and comes to this answer(by using merge):
data3 <- merge(x=Data1,y=Data2,by="customer_id",all.x=TRUE)
data4 <- data3[is.na(data3$No_of_products_ordered),]

which gives the following output:

```
customer_id    name            product   sales      No_of_products_ordered  response
       1       Rahul Ranjan    mixer     3                   <NA>           <NA>
       3       P Paul          mixer     3                   <NA>           <NA>
       5       Sunny Tiwari    toaster   2                   <NA>           <NA>
       7       Ambreen Khan    lcd tv    1                   <NA>           <NA>
```

Comment: @Thomas i have tried this using merge though it is giving the columns No_of _products_ordered and response column also.

Answer (score 0):

This one is by using sqldf:

data5 <- sqldf("select a.customer_id , a.name
                              from Data1 a
                              left join Data2 b
                         on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
                      where b.No_of_products_ordered is null")